# Instance member 'showToast' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, instance, toast

I have been trying to add a toast message by following the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2tq4RMcAJw
However, it keeps on giving me the error

> Instance member 'showToast' can't be accessed using static access.

[image: error]

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Make Sure to put the code instead of image of code. Any ways have you added the plugin of Flutter Toast? In you pubspec.yaml file https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast

Comment: Oops! I forgot to run "flutter pub get"  command. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try type flutter pub add fluttertoast and flutter pub get. close and open your editor, try run again

Comment: This is not an answer you can explain them by commenting only.